# How to Generate a Migration Script in the Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, migration, devops, pipeline

I'm building a pipeline for the Asp.Net Core project in Azure DevOps. I'm not able to generate a migration script during build stage. It's failing with an error
`"Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')"`
We didn't add appsettings.json file into the project to avoid conflicts between local environments (I believe that in general it's not required).

I used this code:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Generate SQL Script'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'ef'
    arguments: 'migrations script --idempotent --project $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Project\Project.csproj --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/migration.sql'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Project'
```

and expected to get migration.sql file

Comment: Can you share the content od migration.sql script? The error may suggest that the error originates from wrong database connection definition. Provide information on how You connect and share the connection string

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When sharing your **minimal issue-reproducible** code please don't forget to remove any sensitive or private information such as token password certificate ip etc. as the community is visible to public. Thx.

Comment: @JakubMałecki migration.sql is not generated because of missing connection string. It should contain all database migrations to be applied on Release stage

Comment: May I know whether running the `dotnet ef migrations script` command on your local machine will reproduce the issue or not? This would be helpful to isolate the issue.

Comment: @AlvinZhao-MSFT locally it's not reproducible. I have appsettings.json with connection string present, so migration file is generated successfully

Comment: So, is there the same `appsettings.json` file in your `Azure Repo` as that in your local repo for your pipeline to consume? If the pipeline lacks the required file, it will fail. By the way, have you tested to clone your remote repo onto a **new** path in the local machine and run the required `dotnet` commands to see if the issue is reproducible?